# To factorize the given expression to get the following: $7+\sqrt{-5}=z+z \sqrt{-5}=z(1+ \sqrt{-5})$, where $z \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Please, check my version:

As $z \in \mathbb{Z} \Rightarrow z = a + ib$, where $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$

Thus

$z(1 + \sqrt{-5}) = (a + ib)(1 + i \sqrt{5}) = a + ai \sqrt{5} + ib + {i}^{2} \cdot b \sqrt{5} = (a - b \sqrt{5}) + i(a \sqrt{5} + b) = 7 + i \sqrt{5}$

Solve the following system of equations:

\begin{cases}
   a - b \sqrt{5} = 7 \\
   a \sqrt{5} + b = \sqrt{5}
 \end{cases}
$\Rightarrow$
\begin{cases}
   a = b \sqrt{5} + 7 \\
   (b \sqrt{5} + 7) \sqrt{5} + b = \sqrt{5}
 \end{cases}
$\Rightarrow$
\begin{cases}
   a = 2 \\
   b= -\sqrt{5}
 \end{cases}
Thus, we get there exist the value $z \in \mathbb{Z}(z = 2 - i \sqrt{5})$ such that 
$7 + \sqrt{-5} = z + z \sqrt{-5}$

Thus, $7 + \sqrt{-5}$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z} \sqrt{-5}$.

Comment: But $2-i\sqrt 5\notin \mathbb Z$! - Also, your computation woul dbe simplified if you first multiplied both sides of $7+\sqrt{-5}=z(1+\sqrt{-5})$ with $1-\sqrt{-5}$

Comment: Have you learned about norms yet? $N(7 + \sqrt{-5}) = 54$, suggesting it might be divisible by some number with a norm of 6 or 9. Insert *Hitchhiker's Guide* joke here if desired.